# Database Design - Read/Delete content according to user rights

Tags: database-design, relational-database, sql-server-2012, database-schema

I am having trouble designing a database/finding a solution to this problem:

I have a page, called Documents, displays content from the 'content' table in my database.

I would like to know how to add user permissions to the content, and I am having trouble combining/designing the database.

How would I solve it?

Database diagram:

[image]

Documents page:

[image]

For example, if a the 'User Type' is Admin I want the user to have Read and Delete permissions, but if the user is 'Normal' (for example) I want the user to be able only to view the content and not delete.

Any ideas on what tables I need to create or what SQL statements I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `permissions` table with two columns: `permission_id` and `name`. This table will have two rows as your problem is currently described: 1-Read, 2-Delete.

You'll then want three more tables: `user_type_permissions`, `role_permissions`, and `user_permissions`. Each of these tables will have foreign keys to the `permissions` table, and also to `user_types`, `roles`, and `users` respectively.